# What are these gray spots on my locoto pepper plant?

Tags: diseases, peppers

Over the past few days I've noticed these grey streaks appearing on some of the leaves of my pepper plant and was wondering if anyone had any insight.

As of now, it seems to be mostly leaves near the bottom of the plant. The leaves aren't crinkly or anything, they're just grey and white with a bit of black. I'm a bit attached to the plant, so if possible I'd like to figure out what to do.
[image]
Thank you in advance[image]
[image]

Comment: Since it almost looks variegated, I would guess it's a virus.